# Angularjs: variables in html attributes and within <style> markup

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, variables

I would like to know how to put an angularjs model as the value for an html attribute. such as:

`<div ng-controller="deviceWidth"
    width={{width}}>
</div>`

also, how would I do this within `<style>` markup? Where would I put ng-controller?

```
div {
    width:{{width}}
}
```

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better do create own custom directive instead of the "static" `width`, and interpret the interpolation with [$observe](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes) function.

Post pretty similar, involving some solutions:
[String Interpolation Won't Work when Setting Attribute Values on a Custom Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645780/string-interpolation-wont-work-when-setting-attribute-values-on-a-custom-direct)

Concerning the  markup, you'd better play with [ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), whose value comes from your controller logic.